# Syntax Clarification using "=>"

Tags: c#, lambda

Can anybody please tell me what is happening in below code in simple English, specifically around the usage of `=>` and `+=` symbols:

```
var ls = new LibraryServiceClient(AppSettings.Get("LibraryServiceBaseAddress"), 
                                  SessionId, App.Id, _user.UUID);
ls.MakingRequest += (s, e) =>
{
    LogStash.LogDebug("Library Service | Before making request  : {0}",
    DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(s,e) => { /*expresion*/ }
```

is a lambda function.

It's type is `Action<object, EventArgs>`.

```
ls.MakingRequest
```

is an event.

With `+=` you register a handler to this event.
When the event is fired all registered handlers will execute.

A handler has the same signature as the action - it takes an `object` sender and  an `EventArgs` eventArgs and returns `void`.
Thus, the lambda function type is compatible, so it will be called when the event is fired.

Answer (score 7):

You assign a new delegate to the event:

```
ls.MakingRequest +=
```

You create a lambda expression, a function having two parameters, `s` and `e`:

```
 (s, e) =>
```

Where the action of the lambda expression is:

```
{ LogStash.LogDebug("Library Service | Before making request  : {0}", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a syntactical sugar to make chained extension methods look more readable.

Below code will explain its evolution:

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // named delegate
        Tasker t = new Tasker();
        t.doer += DoProvider.DoThis;
        t.CallDoer("I am doing something");

        // anonymous method
        Tasker t2 = new Tasker();
        t2.doer += delegate(string s){
            Console.WriteLine (s);
        };
        t2.CallDoer("I am doing something again");

        // syntactical sugar over anonymous methods aka lambda expressions
        Tasker t3 = new Tasker();
        t3.doer += (s)=>{
            Console.WriteLine (s);
        };
        t3.CallDoer("I am doing yet another thing");
    }
}


public delegate void DoSomething(string Foo);

public class Tasker
{
    public event DoSomething doer;

    public void CallDoer(string s)
    {
        doer.Invoke(s);
    }
}

public static class DoProvider
{
    public static void DoThis(string Bar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (Bar);
    }
}
```